# What is the equivalent of sysdeo for developing applications in Eclipse Helios for Websphere 7?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, environment

What is the equivalent of sysdeo for developing applications in Eclipse Helios for Websphere 7?

I am looking for a plugin that allows the deployment and debugging of Java EE applications in Eclipse using WebSphere.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1) (not necessarily Juno) edition and install [WebSphere® Application Server Developer Tools](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/wasdev/entry/download_wdt?lang=en).

Another option is to use [Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software](http://www-142.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/application/) which is an Eclipse based environment for developing WebSphere applications.